# コメント入力中にEnterを押すと送信してしまう

Tags: バグ, 完了, コメント

[別の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)で送信されないようになってる、とありますが自分の環境（Mac 10.11.5,
Firefox 47.0 & Safari 9.1.1）では変換の決定時に送信されます。

---

When I select a character with enter on OS X 10.11.5 and either Firefox 47.0 or Safari 9.1.1, it submits the comment.

I am using the default IME, and can reproduce the bug with the Live Conversion setting either on or off.

Comment: MacのデフォルトIMEを利用していますか？

Comment: デフォルトIMEで、ライブ変換のon/offに関わらず起きてました。このコメントを書いている今現在は問題ありません（設定を戻したから？）

Comment: その通りです。設定で「Return」が決定しないように更新しました。IME関連は開発者に報告します。

Comment: Macでのコメント入力中、また同じ問題が発生するようになってしまっています。

Comment: 自分の環境でも同じ状態が発生しています。Google日本語入力をしようしています

Comment: とりあえず、Macからの(普通にことえりです)の入力では、現象が出なくなりました。

Comment: 解決したとの報告が6月末にMeta.SEに投稿されているので、completedとしました。 [Improved IME Handling is now active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280734/improved-ime-handling-is-now-active)

Comment: ここ最近でも発生しているような気がします……(macのGoogle日本語入力です)

Comment: Fedora 25 + IBUS + Mozc ですが, 同様の問題があるようです.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2014年末にこのバグを把握した時、コメントで「Return/Enter」を押したら送信しない設定をしました。

先週この問題を治そうとしたら、再現ができなかったため、その設定をオフしました。

とりあえず、元の設定に戻して、このバグを再現出来るかを検討します。