# コメント入力中でのEnterの動作

Tags: サポート, 完了, コメント

[Enterキーでコメントを送信することができない / I can't press enter to send a comme](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1780/enter%e3%82%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%81%a7%e3%82%b3%e3%83%a1%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e9%80%81%e4%bf%a1%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-i-cant-press-enter-to-send-a-comment)

[コメント入力中にEnterを押すと送信してしまう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2214/)

という質問があるのですが、現状どうなっているのでしょうか。

Firefox + Windows + ATOK の環境ですが、コメントのフィールドにフォーカスがある状態でEnter押すと送信されてしまうのでしょっちゅう誤爆してしまいます。(IME使用中の変換確定時のEnterで送信されると言う話ではありません。)

Enterで送信されないよう変更をリクエストします。

Comment: Google Chrome 58 + Ubuntu 16.10 + Mozc でも Enter で送信されてしまいます。

Comment: 一応、Shift-Enterで改行ができるようにはなっているようです

Comment: @KiYugadgeter  改行したいのではなく意図せずコメントが投稿されてしまうという話です

Comment: 開発者と確認します。Max OSX 10.11.6とChrome 58だとEnterを押すと送信されませんが、たまになぜか送信します。

Comment: 現在の使用感はいかがでしょうか。
回答で説明された改善で問題無さそうでしょうか。
もし、現在もEnterキーの挙動に問題を感じていらっしゃる場合は、 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3923/ でご意見いただければと思います。

Comment: この質問の意図はスタックオーバーフローでコメントの時にEnterキーを押してもコメント発信しないようにしてもらいたいという要望だと思います、私も同じ要望を提出したいですが、新しい質問を作った方がいいでしょうか。（このコメントを打つ時でも誤って3回コメント送信してしまっています、日本語の場合は command + Enterでコメントを送信した方がユーザ体験がいいと思います）

Comment: しかもコメントは５分間しか編集できませんし、この問題が６年間も放置されていてどれだけの日本語ユーザがこの痛みを味わっていたかのは知らないです。（このコメントを打つ時は2回Enterキーで送信してしまいました。。）

Answer (score 5):

2016 年 6 月 30 日の時点で、[改善された IME 処理が Stack Exchange ネットワーク全体に実装されました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280734/335251)。現在、日本語 IME モードで <kbd>Enter</kbd> キーが押された場合、コメントは投稿されません (ただし、英語モードでは投稿されます)。日本語 IME モードで入力中に <kbd>Enter</kbd> キーを押してもコメントが投稿されないという、意図したとおりに現在も機能していることを開発者が確認済みです。

この状態でバグが発生した場合 (つまり日本語 IME モードで入力中に<kbd>Enter</kbd> キーを押してコメントが投稿されてしまう場合)、新しいメタ投稿を作成して問題を報告してください。その場合は、開発者がバグをより迅速に特定して修正できるように、バグを再現するのに役立つ関連情報 (OS やブラウザーのバージョンなど) を含めてください。ご協力ありがとうございます！

Comment: モードがどうであろうと、Enterで送信されないようにしてほしいというのがリクエストの趣旨です。